# IOSurface gradually increases memory in iOS 12 and above

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, iosurface

I am facing memory issue in my app for iOS 12 and above versions. **IOSurface** gradually increases simultaneously in iOS 12.1.1 where as it works fine in iOS 11 versions. I have attached the issue screenshot below,

[image]

Why this issue happens in iOS 12 versions? Can someone help me how to solve this? I cross checked in iOS 11 versions and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use camera ?

It may depends on camera.

[image]
Size of IOSurface bock: 8372224 bytes = 1960*1080*4

Comment: Yes am using that. But for me it shows on CoreUI components(_csiCompressImageProviderCopyIOSurfaceWithOptions). Did you know any solution for this please let us know. Thanks.

Comment: I found the issue, UIImage(imageNamed:"bgImg") is the cause of IOSurface increase. So I tried alternate way by using Image(data:"data") and it works stable.

Comment: @Madhavan Do you mean to say `UIImage(data:)`?